# LazyItemScope code not executing when placed in HorizontalPager

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

The code below shows that all code is being executed except debug line number 4. I do realise that the `HorizontalPager` is experimental, but perhaps there is another reason I cannot execute it? It is not null.

```kotlin
// ProfileViewModel.kt
class ProfileViewModel : ViewModel() {
    var lazyListScope: LazyListScope? = null
    ...
}
```

```kotlin
// MAIN SCREEN FUNCTION
@ExperimentalPagerApi
@ExperimentalMaterialApi
@Composable
fun ScreenProfile() {
    val viewModel = viewModel<ProfileViewModel>()
    val tabs = listOf(
        TabItem.Feed,
        TabItem.Ads,
        TabItem.Seeking
    )

    val pagerState = rememberPagerState()
    var scope: LazyListScope? = null

    LazyColumn {
        viewModel.lazyListScope = this
        item {
            UserProfileSection()
            Tabs(tabs = tabs, pagerState = pagerState)
        }
    }
    TabsContent(tabs = tabs, pagerState = pagerState)
}
```

```kotlin
@ExperimentalPagerApi
@Composable
fun TabsContent(tabs: List<TabItem>, pagerState: PagerState) {
    val viewModel = viewModel<ProfileViewModel>()
    // viewModel.lazyListScope is of type LazyListScope
    Log.d("LazyDebug","1. Hello from TabsContent()")
    viewModel.lazyListScope?.item {
        Log.d("LazyDebug","2. Hello from TabsContent().lazyListScope")
    }
    HorizontalPager(state = pagerState, count = tabs.size) { page ->
        Log.d("LazyDebug","3. Hello from TabsContent().HorizontalPager")
        viewModel.lazyListScope?.item {
            Log.d("LazyDebug","4. Hello from TabsContent().HorizontalPager.lazyListScope")
        }
        tabs[page].content()
    }
    viewModel.lazyListScope?.item {
        Log.d("LazyDebug","5. Hello from TabsContent() end.")
    }
}
```

Here is the output:

```
2021-12-21 09:12:33.746 14796-14796/com.example.practice D/LazyDebug: 1. Hello from TabsContent()
2021-12-21 09:12:34.752 14796-14796/com.example.practice D/LazyDebug: 2. Hello from TabsContent().lazyListScope
2021-12-21 09:12:34.754 14796-14796/com.example.practice D/LazyDebug: 5. Hello from TabsContent() end.
2021-12-21 09:12:34.774 14796-14796/com.example.practice D/LazyDebug: 3. Hello from TabsContent().HorizontalPager
2021-12-21 09:12:34.780 14796-14796/com.example.practice D/LazyDebug: 3. Hello from TabsContent().HorizontalPager
```

Comment: What's your expected behaviour? By doing `viewModel.lazyListScope?.item {` you're adding an item to your `lazyListScope`, but it doesn't seems being part of your composable tree. Where from `viewModel.lazyListScope` value is coming into the view model? It's part of composable lifecycle and shouldn't be stored inside a view model or used outside of the lambda on which it was called, e.g. inside `LazyColumn`

Comment: It may work somehow if called on the same recomposition with parent view (e.g. `LazyColumn`), but it's still shouldn't be used like this, and `HorizontalPager` will recompose its pages separately.

Comment: What I'm trying to have is a `LazyList`. It would have two items, a profile section, the tab selection panel and the content. The content would display a list of some composables. Obviously my current approach with taking `lazyListScope` and using it outside the lambda does not work...